# SQL: Join on multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to join the following tables:

```
Table 1: users (id, name)
Table 2: pivot_table (user_id, user_id2)
```

This table hold the relationship between the users. One user can be related to many other users.

```
Table 3: contacts (id, user_id, name)
```

I am trying to select a user and then find its related users and contacts.
I have tried to use the join, i am successfully able to get either the contacts or the users but not the both.

I used the following query:

```
select
    contacts.id as contact_id,
    users.id as user_id,
    pivot.user_id2 as user2_id
from
    `contacts`
    inner join `users` on  `contacts`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
    inner join `pivot` as `pivot` on `pivot`.`user_id` = `contacts`.`user_id`
```

Suppose i have the following data in the tables
**Users:**

```
id, name
1, Sahil
2, Shubham
3, Xyz
```

**Pivot table data**

```
id, user_id, user_id2
1, 1, 2
```

**Contacts table data**

```
id, user_id, name
1, 1, Abc
2, 1, XYZ
```

**Now what is get from the query is**

```
contact_id, user_id, user_id2
1, 1, 2
2, 1, 2
```

but what i need is

```
contact_id, user_id, user_id2
1, 1, null
2, 1, null
null, 1, 2
```

I am not able to figure out what wrong i am doing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by myself with the use of Union.

I joined the users, pivot table and performed an union with the contacts table to get the desired results.

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look into the different `JOIN` types.

With an `INNER JOIN` as you have here the result will only include rows for cases where a match is found in all the sources.

With a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` the result will include rows for all data in one side of the join even if there is no match at the other side (columns `SELECT`ed from the other side will come out as `NULL`).

With a `FULL OUTER JOIN` you will get rows output for all three conditions (match both sides, data on left with no match on right, and data on right with no match on left). I think this is what you want for the join between `contacts` and `users`.

Note that the word "outer" is usually optional so you could write `LEFT JOIN` instead of `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

---

This page has a useful diagram of join types: http://stevestedman.com/2015/03/mysql-join-types-poster/

It suggests that mySQL doesn't support `FULL OUTER` joins (which I didn't know was the case) so you will need to `UNION` two selects, one with a `RIGHT` join and one with a `LEFT` to get the sort of result you are looking for.